# How to convert image in aforge

Tags: aforge, convolution

I have a question. I would like to convert an image in Gaussian Sharpen, but I don't know how to create "image" argument.

That's my code:

```
int[,] kernel = {
            { -2, -1,  0 },
            { -1,  1,  1 },
            {  0,  1,  2 } };


Convolution filter = new Convolution(kernel);
filter.ApplyInPlace(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

The ApplyInPlace method has three main overloads. Each one takes a different image class type: [UnmanagedImage](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/44eeefe9-edc4-ff89-38e5-1a057bed78e4.htm), [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e7y164x) and [BitmapData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata). The first class type is an AForge.NET class while the two other are under the System.Drawing namespace.

To create an UnmanagedImage you can either use the constructor, or one of the static methods: [Create](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/46f3cade-4c42-491f-2a51-27b8c3d7f1a1.htm) and [FromManaged](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/b9a9e9c5-2bd1-1a45-ed6c-4bef5172e4b2.htm).
You can create a Bitmap with AForge.NET static method [Image.FromFile](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/4b467feb-9cf0-c2b5-4a16-a1862d6e2531.htm), or [read the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e7y164x).
The BitmapData class is obtained from the Bitmap class by calling the [LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d) method.

If you take a look at the samples installed with AForge.NET you will also find working examples of using these methods.